# Q regarding PTJ and bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty, purim-torah-policy

Your Purim Torah policy states that Purim Torah questions may be posted or answered until 2 days after the end of Purim.

Usually bounties last about a week. If I put a bounty on my or someone else's Purim Torah question, close to the deadline, and you close the question just after Purim, wouldn't that conflict with the bounty policy?

Comment: Questions with bounties can't be closed, I think.

Comment: @DoubleAA But the bounty can be refunded by a mod and then the question closed.

Comment: @Scimonster Yes. Should that be the policy?

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, we have a rule that PT questions get closed after Purim, so it seems only fair to close even questions with bounties. I might give those a bit more time; leave a comment asking the OP award the bounty, and then refund if they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting corner case.  Questions with bounties can't be closed and a bounty must run for at least 24 hours before being awarded.

**For this year** I propose: still-active bounties must be awarded as soon after the end of PTIJ season as the interface allows (you won't get your full week), and if that means moderators have to delay closing *that question only* by a day, so be it.  We didn't anticipate the problem and it's a little late to spring a rules change now.

**For the future** I propose requiring that bounties be awarded before the end of PTIJ season, which means starting them in time to do that.  Unfortunately the only enforcement here is that moderators can refund bounties, but that's not quite fair -- a bounty buys *publicity*, and refunding doesn't undo that.  So we'll need people to be careful to actually award their bounties.

Comment: Sounds like a fair plan for next year. Only thing I can think of is related to questions posted close to the end date of PTIJ that remain unanswered. I think it takes 2 days before someone can post the bounty to start.

Comment: That's true -- so you couldn't offer a bounty on a question that was asked later than three days before the end of the season.  Questions coming in that late have limited opportunity anyway, but remember that people can ask for old questions to be reopened the following year.  So maybe in that case you just have to wait -- set yourself a reminder or something if necessary.